# Python Exception invalid syntax

Tags: python

Python `except` don't work. I'm trying

```
r = requests.get('URL') # URL returns something like: {"code": ["12345678"]} 
print(r.text)
parse = json.loads(r.text)

getcode = False
while not getcode:
    time.sleep(2)
    codeparse = parse["code"]
    print("Unable to get SMS Code, sleeping for 2 seconds...")
except KeyError:
    pass

getcode = parse["code"]
```

I've tried everything I know. Is there something I need to import or something I'm missing?

Edit: Updated to add more code as requested.

Comment: More code is necessary. There must be something going wrong. Also ```except KeyError``` is only going to detect ```KeyError```. If you want it for all errors then use ```except Exception```. But this will supress all error. Also, ```except``` should always go with ```try```

Comment: It's impossible to see what the problem is with the given information. For all we know it might be an indentation issue...Please add a proper code snippet.

Comment: need at least `try` block and python version.

Comment: Please post your code here indented exactly as it is in your IDE, and post the exact error as python shows it

Comment: You have no `try`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you're trying to read the value in the dictionary `parse` with key `"code"`, and if there is no such entry, then you wait 2 seconds to try again.

Try this:

```
print(r.text)
parse = json.loads(r.text)

while True:
    try:
        codeparse = parse["code"]
        break
        
    except KeyError:
        print("Unable to get SMS Code, sleeping for 2 seconds...")
        time.sleep(2)

print("The value is", codeparse)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is simply invalid syntax: you can't have an `except` block as part of the `while` loop:

```
while not getcode:
    ...
except KeyError:
    pass
```

Example in the REPL:

```
>>> while 1:
...  print("g")
... except KeyError:
  File "<stdin>", line 3
    except KeyError:
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

So, you immediately get a `SyntaxError`, no matter what's inside the loop.

The proper syntax is:

```
try:
   # some code
   ...
except KeyError:
   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how the try except method works...
Try some statement(s) and if it raises some error, then the except block will be run

```py
try:
    print(0/0)
except KeyError:
    print('keyerror')
    '''in this block you can add what will happen if the error 
    raised in the try block raises an KeyError'''
except:
    print('some error occured')
```